# Notation of the identity element in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

Is there any special reason why the identity element in a group is commonly denoted by $e$ in abstract algebra?

Comment: e needed some lurve :-P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of the German word 'Einheit'(e) which was used by Heinrich Weber in his Lehrbuch der Algebra (1896).